# Magento Rule Based Related Products

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, rules, product-relations, related-products

We are attempting to set up Rule Based Relations, a feature of Magento Enterprise.
Specific Magento version is EE 1.13.1.0

So basically you set which products are the related products, and which products to attach/relate those too.

We set up the rules, and the products did not display any related products at all.

Attach one product manually as a related, and it does the 1 manual, and the other 3 rule-based.

Then I set the relation types to "rule based only" and then it was 4 rule-based related products.

Then I removed the single manual product, and then no related products show up. Even though the rule is still in place, and it is set to use rules only.

Is there a bug with this feature, or some way to fix it?

I have been reindexing and clearing cache at each step/phase of this process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->catalog->rule based product relations`,

and change Show **Related** Products, Show **Cross-Sell** Products & Show **Upsell** Products

from "**Rule-Based Only**" to "**Both selected and rule-based**"

then, `reindex` & `flush` cache

Comment: On which table rules are saved ?